# What's a word for being proud of someone else without suggesting that you had anything to do with their accomplishment?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word to suggest that I'm very pleased with somebody's commendable actions. This keeps coming up! For instance, say a friend or family member does something awesome. What I feel like saying is "I'm proud that you made that decision or were able to do that," but that feels so condescending/unfitting in many contexts.

I need something more outwardly directed.

Comment: Why just one word? Why not simply, "Well done!" Is that sufficiently outer directed? Seems so to me. Don

Comment: "Well Done" is as close as I've gotten to a phrase. I guess I had been hoping for a word or words that have suggested a joy on the makers' behalf

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you're going to find a single word, because *pride* has two aspects to it:

> 1) Feeling pleasure or satisfaction 2) about an achievement (your own or someone else's).

I think the easiest thing would be to use a word that means pleasure/satisfaction and then just say why this feeling has been elicited.

You could use the word from your own post: *pleased*:

> I'm pleased you made that decision.

Or perhaps the word *glad*:

> I'm glad you made that decision.

Both of these avoid the gushing nature of *proud*.

Depending on context, you could use an intensifier such as *really glad*.

Comment: "I'm pleased you made that decision" is what Lord Crawford, famous for his sarcastic disposition, used to say to his servants. "I'm glad you made that decision" sounds like a pirate, grappling hook in hand, talking to the captain of the surrendered ship.

Comment: The gushing nature is part of it!

Comment: Gushing, as in overly-exagerated praise. You said you wanted to avoid sounding condescending. If the word *proud* isn't over-the-top for your purposes, then why do you think it sounds condescending?

Comment: @Ricky. If you say it in your head in a sarcastic tone, then yes, it will sound sarcastic. Similarly, if you say it in a pirate voice, you will sound like a pirate. If you say it in heartfelt way, neither of these would apply. As far as "made that decision", I'm assuming OP would actually mention what the thing is, as in "You know, I'm really glad you decided to go to university".

Comment: "I'm pleased" sounds fine to me, or "I'm happy" if you prefer. As others have said, there is nothing that can't sound insincere or sarcastic.

Answer (score 1):

The first word that comes to mind is *appreciative*. I'm not too sure if that fits what you're looking for, but there are words quite similar to the former: indebted, grateful, obliged, and more.

Answer (score -2):

Pride is a sin:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_deadly_sins

You might want to try, depending on the person's age and background -

"I'm truly awed by what you did there!" 
"I really admire you for the things you've been doing"
"That's just admirable, dude! Seriously!"
"That's really commendable!"

etc.

Comment: So is lust. It's still pretty great in the right context.